# file save with static method for multiple users at the same time , is this static method is safer if multiple user save the file at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, static, static-methods

I am using this method for saving the file on the server I want to know that if this method is using by multiple users at the same time,

more information is that: this method is called from the  JsonResult of asp.net MVC application and this method saves the file on the server and return path to the JsoneResult such path is saved in database.

1: is it a safe way to store files even multiple users are online at the same time.

```
    public static string SaveImageToServer(dynamic Image, string FolderPath, string FolderRootPath)
    {
            if (Image != null)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase _image = (HttpPostedFileBase)Image;
                string fileExtention = _image.FileName.Substring(_image.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                FUN.CreateMosDocInnerDir(FolderPath.ToString());
                string ImgName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmssfffff");
                string CreatedFileCompletePath = "/" + FolderRootPath + "/" + FolderPath.ToString() + "/" + FolderPath.ToString() + "_" + ImgName + fileExtention;
                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" + CreatedFileCompletePath);
                _image.SaveAs(path);
                return CreatedFileCompletePath;
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: If the question is "can two users get the same file name?" the answer is yes. But that's not because the method is static. It's because you are using the time as the filename which could be the same if two calls are virtually simultaneous.

Comment: if 2 or more than 2 users calls this function at the same time then the 2nd and 3rd parameters will be different.

Comment: 1:is it possiable two user call at the same time and both get same **return result **?
2: and is it possiable the user1 file will save on server and for user2 file will not save on server and both user got the same result.

Comment: If those parameters are different, then no. Static methods do not share variables declared within them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking if the variables within the method could be shared between two callers simultaneously, the answer is no. Variables within a static method are not shared across calls - only *static properties* of a class are shared.

If two callers call the method with exactly the same parameters at exactly the same time, then they could either write over each other, or the second could get an exception that the file exists, or something else if `SaveAs` is not thread-safe.